# Why word "very" is used in combination with words like "first", "last", ect

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Wow, my first question here :) Recently i watched a tennis match and the commentator said "This is his very first title". I've also heard the opposite expression "This is his very last chance". So why is word **very** used and how it strengthens the meaning of the next word if not the whole sentence? :)